# В чём конкретно опасность eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

Хочу сделать связь с сервером через `eval`.
В чём опасность подобной логики?

Клиент:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/actions/test.php',
    data: { 'test': 'test' },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        eval(result);
    }
});
```

Сервер:

```
if (isset($_POST['test']) && !empty($_POST['test'])) {
    exit('alert("Ok")');
} else {
    exit('alert("Error")');
}
```

Comment: @Grundy, это всё шаблонные отговорки. Вот вам конкретный пример, где опасность?

Comment: В искусственных примерах как привило всегда безопасно. если ответ всегда будет именно _'alert("Ok")'_ - то все безопасно, но нет смысла в использовании `eval`, который можно заменить на `alert` которому передавать строчку для отображения

Comment: @Grundy, будут ответы типа алерт(ошибка), location.reload(); append и тд

Comment: @pavel каким же образом?

Comment: @pavel, он просто скрипт подменит - зачем ему eval?

Comment: В общем, ничего путного не ответили как и в других подобных вопросах.

Comment: @Rammsteinik этот код станет небезопасным сразу, как только внутри возвращаемой строки появится переменная на значение которой можно повлиять извне: exit("alert('OK + ".$_GET['externalInput']."')"). В вашем случае, вообще ajax и eval использовать не обязательно, достаточно просто добавлять и удалять <script> c src="/actions/test.php" в dom, каждый вызов.

Comment: На клиенте относительно безопасно, другое дело что это весьма корявое решение, но иногда оно имеет место для жизни, вот на сервере это потенциальная ОГРОМНАЯ дыра в безопасности.

Comment: @vnn198 как насчёт new Function?

Comment: а что с ним не так?